# $3\times3$ matrix with 5 eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A differentail equations exercise asks for the eigenvectors of
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3&2&4\\
2&0&2\\
4&2&3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The answer in the back of the book gives
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1\\
2
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-4\\
1
\end{bmatrix};$$
the first two have eigenvalues $-1$, the second has eigenvalue $8$.  Mathematica confirms this:

```
A = {{3, 2, 4}, {2, 0, 2}, {4, 2, 3}};
v2 = {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, -4, 1}}
Table[A.v2[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]

{{2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, -4, 1}}
{{16, 8, 16}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 4, -1}}
```

However, Mathematica gives the eigenvectors as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1\\
2
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
0
\end{bmatrix};$$
and then confirms them as eigenvectors:

```
A = {{3, 2, 4}, {2, 0, 2}, {4, 2, 3}};
v = Eigenvectors[A]
Table[A.v[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]

{{2, 1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 2, 0}}
{{16, 8, 16}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, -2, 0}}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If there is any eigenvector at all, there will always be infinitely many.

Comment: I guess I was just being stupid.  Clearly $A(3v) = 3Av = 3\lambda v = \lambda3v$.

Comment: A linear combination of eigenvectors with exactly the same eigenvalues is another eigenvector

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Should I delete the question or leave it for the other poor souls that make the same mistake?

Comment: @JacobBond if you feel that you understand the answer well enough now, feel free to post an answer yourself

Comment: Don't delete the question! A learning experience is *always* worth sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

Any scalar multiple $\mu$ of an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is an eigenvector:
$$A(\mu v) = \mu Av = \mu \lambda v = \lambda(\mu v).$$

More complete answer:

As Will Jagy points out in the comments, any linear combination of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ with be an eigenvector for $\lambda$:

$$A\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mu_{i}v_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mu_{i} Av_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mu_{i}\lambda v_{i} = \lambda\sum_{I = 1}^{n}\mu_{i}v_{i}.$$